# How to deploy wildfly EAR application on opshift 3

Tags: java, jboss, openshift, wildfly, ear

Am trying to deploy my wildfy 10 EAR application to openshift.

I have successfully completed the following process.

1. Push project to a git repository
2. Create a openshift project
3. Create a openshift application in the project
4. Point application to the git repository
5. Configured webhook for the project.

The challenge now is that any time i try to access my application from the link i was given am directed to this page
[image: wildfly welcome page]

I was actually expecting that i will directed to my project index.jsp page, just as it does on my localhost.

I also clicked on the Administration Console and still nothing, i cant login,

What am i missing please, how do i make my project work the way it's meant to.

Thank you.

Comment: make sure admin console is enabled in the deployed wildfly. it usually happens if it is not enabled or no user is defined to login.

Comment: @techtrainer done. created a user from my local admin console, and its been enabled all along. Its still the same

Comment: have you enabled management console similar to, https://access.redhat.com/solutions/192483

Comment: how do i access the deployed standalone.xml, is there anyway to get it from web console?

Comment: either package your jboss with updated file or ssh to deployed container and then update as shown in solution. easy way would be to pre-package your jboss with file required.

Comment: i have package with required the required files